# NFC-list Unable to find USB buses (No such file or directory) with ACR122U reader writer

Tags: windows-10, usb, nfc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I received my ACR122U NFC reader/writer 3 days ago, and had to find a way to get "libnfc" and "libsub" installed so I could try something in Windows Subsystem for Linux since the one specific project (which I will not talk about). I tried the "nfc-list" command, and it returned these two errors:

error libnfc.buses.usbbus Unable to find USB busses (No such file or directory)
error libnfc.buses.usbbus Unable to find USB busses (No such file or directory)

I tried searching for an answer or solution on Google, and yet there were no good results for this issue. Is there a way I can fix this for my USB NFC device for WSL2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you need to enable your system to have access to the usb devices.
After that there is an issue with the fact that the only way is via USBIP, which is not passthrough.
This means that NFC-list will not list them properly.

Unfortunately you either need to try with VMware/VBox or with a proper installation of Linux